# VBA Code for Excel that Pulls Data in/ Recalculates workbook and then PDF hourly Runs fine initially eventually starts PDFing blank sheets

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, optimization

As title suggests I have reworked a VBA code that basically runs every hour on the hour (or when it initially gets started). It refreshes the connection and then recalculates the sheets, PDFs the file and saves in 3 separate file locations. It's a pretty basic code but I can't get it to run consistently. Usually it PDFs 3-4 times (3-4 hours) before I start getting a PDF of blank pages and excel has to be forced closed and restarted. Then it runs fine again. Sometimes but not all the time I see the "Not enough resources to display" message from excel. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub RecalcPDF()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 On Error Resume Next
'looks to find data in the table, writes the message, sends the message, and tells the timer to reset
Application.OnTime Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("A28") + Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("A27"), 
"RecalcPDF", Schedule:=False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("A1") = Now
Sheets("Manual Inputs").Select
Sheets("Manual Inputs").Activate
ActiveSheet.Calculate
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.Calculate


Dim FileName As String
Dim Path As String
    FileName = Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("D44")
    Path = Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("D43")
    '## Add the PATH and EXTENSION to the filename
    FileName = Path & FileName & ".pdf"
    
    FileName2 = Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("D47")
    Path2 = Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("D46")
    '## Add the PATH and EXTENSION to the filename
    FileName2 = Path2 & FileName2 & ".pdf"
    
    FileName3 = Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("D50")
    Path3 = Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("D49")
    '## Add the PATH and EXTENSION to the filename
    FileName3 = Path3 & FileName3 & ".pdf"
    
With Sheets(Array("Daily Dose Display", "Station")).Select
Sheets("Daily Dose Display").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FileName2, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FileName3, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    
End With
Application.OnTime Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("A28") + Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("A27"), 
"RecalcPDF", Schedule:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Comment: You'll never know if there is an error because of the _On Error Resume Next_ statement. I suggest you remove that and the _Application.ScreenUpdating = False_ statements to give yourself a fighting chance of figuring out what's going wrong. Then I would suggest you add some logging statements so you can examine the values of the relevant variables when an error occurs.

Comment: Removed statements, code got hung up on the, "Application.OnTime Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("A28") + Sheets("Manual Inputs").Range("A27"), 
"RecalcPDF", Schedule:=False"   Part with an error. Researching said it cant be false if it isnt scheduled. Deactivated that, and it ran 7 iterations before corrupting. When clicking workbook it was frozen stuck in the simultaneous "publishing" and "saving" of the PDF and I had to hard close Excel. So still in the similar situation, different version of it. Still researching logging, but the PDF function seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track. Logging can be as simple as a function which writes a message to a text file. If it's not practical to step through the code in the debugger, logging is your next best option to trace the execution path and record the values of all the variables when an error occurs.

Comment: Found another person struggling with a similar issue who stated he fixed it by putting a pause between each PDF save. Maybe Excel gets hung up creating the next PDF while the first one is still finishing. I added a 3 second pause between the 3 PDF saves and am currently testing. If testing that option fails, will try and implement logging.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *very* basic logging implementation you can try.

```
Public Sub WriteLog(ByVal msg As String)

    Dim fh As Integer
    
    fh = FreeFile
    Open "C:\Users\user\Documents\application.log" For Append As #fh
    Print #fh, Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:nn:ss> ") & msg
    Close #fh

End Sub
```

Then you might use it like this

```
WriteLog "RecalcPDF: Exporting sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name & " to file " & FileName

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```